# Проблемы с динамическим обновлением страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть ajax запрос для динамического обновления части страницы.
`page1.php`, к которой я обращаюсь, содержит и запрос к базе данных, и jquery код. Вот только все выводится нормально, а jquery код, содержащийся в `page1.php`, не работает.
Делаю все очень коряво, но может кто надоумит, как заставить работать jquery код.

```
$('#knopa1').click(function(){
   var user = <?php echo $uss; ?>;
   var ser = <?php echo $id_s; ?>;              
     $.ajax({
        url: "page1.php",
        data:"user=" + user + "&ser=" + ser,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          $("#content").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

После команды

```
 $("#content").html(html);
```

выполните команду

```
 $('#content').trigger('create');
```

Comment: не, не получается

Comment: @AlexProsto, ошибки выполнения javascript в консоли браузера есть?

Comment: не там у меня все чисто, просто как будто код не подключается и все